# Clicks and Impressions data not importing when i use Big Query Data Transfer to import the DCM Data

Tags: google-bigquery

Received below error once Data Transfer run for the latest day

Summary :
Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.; JobID: 1022925260321:dcm_dt_5e557413-0000-2236-a5f2-883d24fa7fb0

Detailed Error:

Job 1022925260321:dcm_dt_5e56ea4b-0000-2a24-b76b-f403045ee2dc (**table p_impression_doubleclickaccountid$20200224**) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.; JobID: 1022925260321:dcm_dt_5e56ea4b-0000-2a24-b76b-f403045ee2dc

Job 1022925260321:dcm_dt_5e557413-0000-2236-a5f2-883d24fa7fb0 (**table p_click_doubleclickaccountid$20200224**) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.; JobID: 1022925260321:dcm_dt_5e557413-0000-2236-a5f2-883d24fa7fb0

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverlfow Rajesh Reddy! The issue you've reported likely related to the source CSV file schema or Bigquery table structure mismatch, give a try and inspect this file more accurately, so far no chances to provide more details without knowing your initial source data, use search option and look for any other contributors progress on the same topic. You are free to get more insights to the original question in order to support you more.

Comment: Thanks @mk_sta for your response. This Data Tansfer is build by Big Query team which imports other data like activity,campaign ,ad and advertisers ..etc with out fail. I knew it's schema miss match. The CSV files at cloud storage are encrypted. I was wondering is there any channel to report this issue to big query support team

Comment: Yes - go to the BigQuery issue tracker.